# Name of multidimensional propagator integral

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, improper-integrals, contour-integration

$$
I_{n,m}(\boldsymbol{x},\boldsymbol{\tau})
=
\dfrac{1}{(2\pi)^{n+m}}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
\cdots
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
\dfrac{e^{i(\boldsymbol{p}\cdot \boldsymbol{x}-\boldsymbol{q}\cdot \boldsymbol{\tau})}}{|\boldsymbol{p}|^2-|\boldsymbol{q}|^2}
d^n\boldsymbol{p} \ d^m\boldsymbol{q}
$$
All bold variables are real euclidean vectors. Vectors $\boldsymbol{p}$ and $\boldsymbol{x}$ have dimension $n$. Vectors $\boldsymbol{\tau}$ and $\boldsymbol{q}$ have dimension $m$

I am having trouble finding documentation on this integral, mostly because I do not know what its commonly named as in the literature. I know its related to propagators in QFT, but I can only find special cases of $n$ and $m$.

Does anyone know if it has a formal name?

### My first attempt

$$
I_{n,m} 
\propto\frac{1}{x^{n}\tau^{m}}
\int_{0}^{\infty}
\int_{0}^{\infty}
(p)^{n/2}(q)^{m/2}\dfrac{J_{n/2-1}(p)J_{m/2-1}(q)}{(p/x)^2-(q/\tau)^2}
\ dq \ dp
$$
Contour integration fails if both dimensions are even.

### Second Attempt

$$
I_{n,m} = \frac{1}{x^{n/2-1}\tau^{m/2-1}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\phi(a)J_{n/2-1}(ax)J_{m/2-1}(a\tau)da
$$
where $\phi(a)$ is a distribution satisfying
$$
\int(\Box I_{n,m}) d^n p d^m q
=
1
$$
and
$$
\Box
=
\frac{1}{x^{n-1}}
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}
\left(
x^{n-1}
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}
\right)
-
\frac{1}{\tau^{m-1}}
\frac{\partial}{\partial \tau}
\left(
\tau^{m-1}
\frac{\partial}{\partial \tau}
\right)
$$
I do not know how to solve for $\phi(a)$.